# How to manage Slick 3.0.0 Database instances in Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.3, hikaricp, slick-3.0

I was wondering how is the right way to manage Slick 3 (3.0.0-RC3 at this moment) database instances in a Play Framework 2.3.x application. According to the upgrade guide, [each instance has a connection pool associated](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0-RC3/upgrade.html#closing-databases).

My guess is that I should handle a single instance of each real database in the entire application, instead of creating an instance per database operation ([like this example](https://github.com/knoldus/play-reactive-slick/blob/master/app/models/DAO.scala#L50-L51)), because the latter implies to also create a pool for each operation. If I follow [the example](https://github.com/knoldus/play-reactive-slick/blob/master/app/models/DAO.scala#L50-L51) and do this:

```
object Thing {
  private def db: Database = Database.forConfig("mydb")

  private val things = TableQuery[Thing]

  def getAll = {
    val curDb = db
    try curDb.run(things.result)
    finally curDb.close
  }
}
```

I end up creating a pool, which creates 10 connections to the database per execution of the `getAll` function, and disposing them after a single query.

However, if I manage the instance as a singleton, I am not sure if it is thread safe, and can be safely used by the many threads that a Play application manages.

This is my database configuration in application.conf:

```
mydb= {
  dataSourceClass = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
  connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1"
  properties = {
    databaseName = "mydb"
    user = "postgres"
    password = "postgres"
    serverName = "localhost"
  }
  numThreads = 10
  connectionPool = HikariCP
}
```

I'm using HikariCP-java6 v2.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create and destroy pools after each query.  That is going be a disaster.  HikariCP is thread-safe.  Though I would suggest, if possible, running the latest (2.3.6).

Answer (score 1):

I still have several questions about what the best practices are but I think if you change

`private def db: Database = Database.forConfig("mydb")`

to

`private val db: Database = Database.forConfig("mydb")`

Notice the change from `def` to `val`.

That should eliminate the creation of a new connection pool for each query.